# dial with modem by AT COMMAND

Tags: c#-3.0, at-command

I write a project with C# and i want to dial by AT COMMAND to other but my project don't work correctly because it make connection correctly and i hear sound of other side but that not hear my sound
my modem is voice
and i use ATDT0941221225425;

Comment: I haven't done this in ages, but did you set up the modem to accept dial tones? I can't recall the exact setting, but something before the ATDT. That only says to dial the tones, but I think you have to tell it to accept them also. Or something like that. I remember always doing 3 things, ATS (silent maybe?), AT??, and then ATDT...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little confusing, but what it seems like you're saying is that your modem does dial and connect, but you don't hear the touch tones?

If this is correct, you may need to add some more commands to your command string.

Try sending ATM1L3 to your modem before you send the DT command. This should set the modem monitor speaker to be on until the carrier signal is detected (M1) and be at maximum loudness (L3).

Unfortunately, I don't have a modem at hand to test this and am primarily working from 15+ year old knowledge.

There's a reference of Hayes modem commands at http://seriss.com/people/erco/unixtools/hayes.html, and the Wikipedia article on the Hayes Command set at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set also has a list.